# UK visitor visa: My status will change between the application and the journey, what should I select?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I have completed my M.Sc. degree this July and I will be going to Germany for PhD which will start from 1st September. From Germany I need to go UK for 3 days (21-23 September) to attend a workshop and I am now applying a Business visitor UK visa for the same.

As a part of UK visa application, it has been asked that ‘What is your current working status’ and the options are:

- employed full time
- employed part time
- student (working)
- student (non working)
- supported by spouse/partner/other
- unemployed

Which one should I select?

Comment: When will you go to Germany? Starting the application from there (with your German visa and work contract in hand) could make things easier. The timeframe is a bit short but it could still work. And if you apply from your current place of residence, the delay is just as short, you might already be gone when the decision comes.

Comment: I am flying to Germany on 17th August and I have got German Visa already. Since I am applying for a visitor visa for UK, it should not take long time?

Answer (score 3):

The question arises a lot, not just for employment status, but for other questions as well, like marital status.

There is no rule covering the situation, but there is a 'best practices' solution....  Put down the correct answer as of the *application date*.  The *application date* is the date when you pay the fee.

Then go to Part 9 of the form (the 'Remarks' section) and include a brief statement that you expect your employment status to change during the life of the visa.  As a template, you can use something like this...

> **Material change of circumstances**:  On (dd/mm/yyyy), my employment
>   status is expected to change from (xxxxx) to (yyyyy).  This is because
>   (zzzzz).

If it changes to something else, or there is some other **material change in your circumstances**, you should contact them and let them know.  This is covered in the undertaking you sign at the bottom of the form...

> I must inform the UK diplomatic mission if there is a material change
>   to my circumstances, or any new information to my application becomes
>   available.

Adding...

There is no legal definition of 'material', the law only uses the word without defining it.  The courts have applied a definition as *any circumstance which would alter or affect the ECO's decision*.  Failure to comply with this definition is grounds for removal or a ban under [Paragraph 321](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/422941/20150406_Immigration_Rules_-_Part_9_final_v4.pdf).